# SonarQube incremental analysis for C#.Net UnitTest

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

I am using SonarQube 4.3 version to show Unit tests and other code metrics analysis results. Now I am looking for incremental preview or mode for my analysis results as described [here](http://www.sonarqube.org/analysis-vs-preview-vs-incremental-preview-in-sonarqube/).

I am looking to see whether the last code checked-in has a 100% unit test coverage, no security violations and has other quality gates passed.

Currently sonar gives overall combined report for all the files within project. Can we have one for the changed files in the last build as well?

Comment: please clarify your question: What are you trying to achieve, what have you tried, and why what you tried isn't working. You've also tagged your question with `c#`, `maven` and `sonar-runner` which makes it quite vague: try to focus on a single project

Comment: edited the question, let me know if that helps?